# DBT - refering a table that uses post-hook

Tags: hook, dbt

I have a sql file that creates a table and in that sql file I am using a post_hook to do an update of some values. This is working.
However I have a second that that references the first one, but the data is coming without the changes made in post_hook.

When I run I see that the run is ok, and the first model is being created before the second one. I don't see any justification why the second table comes with the data outdated.

Comment: Please update your post to include a sample model with the post_hook + configuration along with the 2nd model that is referencing the first. Also, what platform are you running this on?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.